# Geolocation double check with high accuracy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I programmed this script and the idea is that this script should double check your location. I'm not sure if this works properly. It should work like this: Get location1, get location2, compare these two coordinates, while they are opposite get location1, and location2 again. Will this work?

```
<script>
    if(navigator.geolocation)
        {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});
        }
        else
        {
        alert("Vaš preglednik ne podržava geolokaciju.");
        }

    var a  = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});
    var b  = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});
    //Greške
    function showError(error)
          {
          switch(error.code)
            {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
              alert("Molimo dopustite lociranje kako bi stranica pravilno radila.");
              break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
              alert("Nema informacija o vašoj lokaciji.");
              break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
              alert("Vrijeme slanja zahtjeva je isteklo.");
              break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
              alert("Oops. Dogodila se greška. To je sve što znamo.");
              break;
            }
          }
    //Provjera
    while( a != b){var a  = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});
                   var b  = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});


        function showError(error)
          {
          switch(error.code)
            {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
              alert("Molimo dopustite lociranje kako bi stranica pravilno radila.");
              break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
              alert("Nema informacija o vašoj lokaciji.");
              break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
              alert("Vrijeme slanja zahtjeva je isteklo.");
              break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
              alert("Oops. Dogodila se greška. To je sve što znamo.");
              break;
            }
          }

    };

     function showPosition(pos)


         {

           //Jordanovac
           if (pos.coords.latitude <= 45.7781 && pos.coords.latitude >= 45.777815 && pos.coords.longitude <= 15.998226 && pos.coords.longitude >= 15.996855)
                {window.location = 'ok!.html';}
else{{window.location = 'error!.html';}
        }
```

In the the script should redirect user.

Comment: But why? I've never ever heard that the HTML5 Geolocation API would return two different values when calling it two times almost at the same time! Don't you trust it or what ?

Comment: Because I figured that when I hit locate button first time it's not so accurate as second time, I don't know why. Or if I want really accurate I can open maps on my phone and let them geolocate me.

Comment: Uh, never heard that, why would it be more accurate the second time? Anyway, good luck, this is beyond me!